# What is the difference between 0.0.0.0:99 and [::]:99?

Tags: networking, socket

My `ss -lt`

shows these lines

```
LISTEN               0                    4096                                127.0.0.53%lo:domain                                    0.0.0.0:*                                        
LISTEN               0                    128                                       0.0.0.0:ssh                                       0.0.0.0:*                                        
LISTEN               0                    4096                                      0.0.0.0:https                                     0.0.0.0:*                                        
LISTEN               0                    4096                                      0.0.0.0:99                                        0.0.0.0:*                                        
LISTEN               0                    4096                                         [::]:http                                         [::]:*                                        
LISTEN               0                    128                                          [::]:ssh                                          [::]:*                                        
LISTEN               0                    4096                                         [::]:https                                        [::]:*                                        
LISTEN               0                    4096                                         [::]:99                                           [::]:*
```

What does [::] stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.0.0.0:99` is IPv4 and `[::]:99` is IPv6

Since IPv6 addresses can be so long, using `::` is shorthand notation that everything in between is a 0. And in your example there are no surrounding hexadecimal digits, so it is the shorthand notation for writing `[0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:99`

Here is another example...this IPv6 address `2001:db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:370:7334` could be rewritten as     `2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334`. The `::` is reserved for the longest consecutive run of zeroes, and if there are multiple of the same length it should be used on the left-most run.

The implication for both `0.0.0.0:99` and `[::]:99` is that the host is listening on TCP port 99 for traffic coming from any IP address.

Comment: This is further described in [RFC 5952](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5952.txt) which also mandates that leading `0` in a block are omitted and that a single block must NOT be shortened with `::`.

Answer (score 1):

`0.0.0.0:99` is indicating a process listening on TCP port 99 on all IPv4 interfaces.

`[::]:99` is indicating a process listening on TCP port 99 on all IPv6 interfaces.